# Where can I find a modern version of the "rock" (or "t") console typeface?

Tags: console, fonts

Back in the Slackware and RedHat-pre-Fedora days, there was a console font called, at times, "rock", or "t". I've searched for this many times, but can't find any reference to it. I thought it would be fun to bring it back on Ubuntu, if possible. Does anyone know what it would be called now, or if there's a TrueType version of it I could put on other systems?

Comment: Is this the font you are looking for? http://i.stack.imgur.com/lvMUZ.png

Comment: Yes, that's the one!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

AFAIK there is no existing ports of this font to any outline variant. Here are however some detail, and hacks, that might help you on the way.

The *t.fnt*, Tektite, was created by the (former?) [clySmic Software](https://web.archive.org/web/20010220064021/http://clysmic.com/software/freeware.html), and likely Ralph B Smith Jr, *President/Chief Programmer/Cook/Bottle Washer*. It is a bitmap font which was included with the VFONT program for DOS and OS/2. It load replacement fonts for VGA systems. It's name given by the author is *Tektite* and described as *”a "Architect" style font.”*

VFONT can be [downloaded](http://cd.textfiles.com/swexplorer/disk1/A011/) in the archives CVFONT.ZIP and CVFONTA.ZIP. The *Tektite* font is part of the latter. The former is an older version only for DOS.

#### VFONT and extraction:

The archive consist of the DOS program, VFONT.COM, OS/2 program VFONT2.EXE, a font database VFONT.DAT and a README.MAN. The VFONT.DAT contains 13 bitmap fonts stored back to back. To extract the Tektite font do:

```
dd if=VFONT.DAT of=t.fnt bs=1 skip=28672 count=4096
```

This gives you a font file of type RAW, which is the one included in e.g. Slackware.

Each font is 4096 bytes. Thus to extract the others simply change the *skip* option. I.e. `c.fnt` which comes after `t.fnt` gives you a skip value of `28672 + 4096 = 32768`. All the fonts are included in Linux, and to do a complete extraction one could do:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

pos=0
for n in s sd r ro rl mu ml t c b m mr sc; do
    dd if=VFONT.DAT of=$n.fnt bs=1 skip=$pos count=4096
    ((pos += 4096))
done
```

... or, of course, download it from one of the various distros that includes them.

These files can be loaded directly in terminal by e.g:

```
setfont t.fnt
```

#### Naming in Linux

The font was given its name in Linux by the options for the VFONT program. Tektite has `/T`. The other fonts are also included, are also named by the command line option for VFONT. (*/S = s.fnt, /SD = sd.fnt, /RO = ro.fnt* ... etc.)

#### RAW fonts

The (obsolete but recognized) [RAW font format](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setfont.8.html#FONT_FORMATS) is the simplest font format there is. It has no header, no footer, no escape bytes etc. It usually has a width of 8 pixels (bits) – as do the VFONT fonts. They always have 256 glyphs.

From this we can easily calculate the height by:

```
      file_size (bits)               8 × 4096
h = -------------------- e.g.  h = ------------- = 16
          w × 256                    8 × 256
```

As all the VFONT fonts has a size of 4096, we also know they're all 16 pixels (bits) in height. That also gives that each glyph is 16 bytes.

#### ASCII rendering

As the fonts conform to ASCII range when it comes to 0x20 (space) – 0x7e (tilde) we can do a simple ASCII rendering of the glyphs.

For example the letter `A` has position 65. As each glyph is 8×16 = 128 bits we have them at 128 / 8 = 16 bytes.

As 65 × 16 = 1040 we can extract the glyph `A` by (here including conversion to binary and replacement of 0's and 1's to make it more readable):

```
xxd -s 1040 -l 16 -b -c 1 t.fnt | cut -d' ' -f 2 | tr 0 ' ' | tr 1 '#'
```

Which gives us:

```
Output from  |          Data in file
 command:    |  Binary:   Hex:  Offset  Offset
             |                  Hex:     Dec:
             |  00000000  00    410     1040
             |  00000000  00    411     1041
   ##        |  00011000  18    412     1042
   ##        |  00011000  18    413     1043
  ####       |  00111100  3c    414     1044
  #  #       |  00100100  24    415     1045
 ##  ##      |  01100110  66    416     1046
 ## ###      |  01101110  6e    417     1047
 #### #      |  01111010  7a    418     1048
###   ##     |  11100011  e3    419     1049
##    ##     |  11000011  c3    41a     1050
##    ##     |  11000011  c3    41b     1051
             |  00000000  00    41c     1052
             |  00000000  00    41d     1053
             |  00000000  00    41e     1054
             |  00000000  00    41f     1055
```

Using some simple C-code we can also render some simple PBM images. Here is sample output from all the fonts in VFONT:

[image: VFONT samples]

#### Editing with FontForge

If you wish to work with the font I guess you might go to *FontForge*. As it does not recognize RAW fonts you have to convert it to another format. One of the simpler conversions could be to BDF. One option is to use [John Elliot's PSF Tools](http://www.seasip.info/Unix/PSF/). First convert from RAW to PSF then PSF to BDF:

```
raw2psf t.fnt t.psf
psf2bdf t.psf t.bdf
```

The BDF file can now be opened in FontForge

As the process is rather simple (and same for all VFONT's) you could also use this script to convert directly to BDF format:

Sample usage:

```
./raw2bdf Tektite t.fnt > t.bdf
```

Gives you the Tektite font as BDF.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    printf "Usage: %s <NAME> <raw-fnt-file>\n" $0
    exit
fi

name=$1
file=$2

cat <<EOM
STARTFONT 2.1
FONT $name
SIZE 16 75 75
FONTBOUNDINGBOX 8 16 0 -4
STARTPROPERTIES 3
FONT_DESCENT 4
FONT_ASCENT 12
DEFAULT_CHAR 255
ENDPROPERTIES
CHARS 256
EOM

hexdump -ve '/1 "%02x\n"' "$file" | awk '
    BEGIN {
        n = 0;
    }
    (!((NR - 1) % 16)) {
        if (n > 0)
            print "ENDCHAR"
        printf "STARTCHAR C00%02x\n"\
                "ENCODING %d\n"\
                "SWIDTH 666 0\n"\
                "DWIDTH 8 0\n"\
                "BBX 8 16 0 -4\n"\
                "BITMAP\n",
                n, n
        ++n
    }
    {
        print $0
    }
    END {
        print "ENDCHAR"
        print "ENDFONT"
    }
'
```

### Other versions

There are several modified versions of the Tektite font. If you search for it, optionally adding e.g. *“clysmic”* to the search phrase you can study on.

### Image rendering

For completeness sake I add the C-code mashed up to create the image above. `display` and `convert` are part of *ImageMagick*.

Sample usage:

```
$ ./fntsampler t.fnt hello a

##                ###     ###           
##                 ##      ##           
##                 ##      ##           
##  ###   #####    ##      ##     ##### 
## ## ## ##   ##   ##      ##    ##   ##
####  ####  ###    ##      ##   ##    ##
###   #######      ##      ##   ##    ##
##    ####         ##      ##   ##    ##
##    ####    ##   ##      ##   ##   ## 
##    ## ######    ##      ##    #####  

$ ./fntsampler t.fnt "Hello World!" > hello.pbm
$ display hello.pbm
```

[image: Hello Wold in Tekite]

The sample image of all fonts above was created by:

```
$ for f in *.fnt; do ./fntsampler "$f" "$(printf "%-6s Hello ABC abc 123" "$f")" | convert - "${f%.*}.png"; done

$ convert -negate -append *.png collection.png
```

Code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int usage(char *me, char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr,
        "Usage: %s <RAW-font-file> \"<string>\" [format] [[invert] | [dot] [blank]]\n\n"
        "  format    p : PBM image (default).\n"
        "            a : ASCII.\n"
        "  invert    i : invert b/w in PBM.\n"
        "  dot\n"
        "  blank       : Dot / blank in ASCII mode.\n\n"
        "%s\n"
        ,
        me, errno ? "" : s
    );
    if (errno)
        perror(s);
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *me = argv[0];
    char buf[4096];
    size_t n;
    char *p;
    int i, j, k;

    FILE *fh;
    char *s;
    char fmt = 'p', dot = '1', blank = '0';

    if (argc < 3)
        return usage(me, "Missing argument(s)");

    if (!(fh = fopen(argv[1], "r")))
        return usage(me, "Unable to open file");
    if ((fread(buf, 1, 4096, fh) != 4096))
        return usage(me, "Bad file size");

    s = argv[2];
    if ((n = strlen(s)) < 1)
        return usage(me, "Empty string");

    if (argc > 3)
        fmt = argv[3][0];
    if (fmt != 'a' && fmt != 'p')
        return usage(me, "Unknown format");

    if (fmt == 'a') {
        dot = argc > 4 ? argv[4][0] : '#';
        blank = argc > 5 ? argv[5][0] : ' ';
    } else {
        if (argc > 4 && argv[4][0] == 'i') {
            dot = '0';
            blank = '1';
        }
        printf("P1\n");
        printf("#Text: \"%s\", using %s\n", s, argv[1]);
        printf("%u 16\n", n * 8);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j < (int)n; ++j) {
            p = buf + (s[j] * 16) + i;
            for (k = 7; k >= 0; --k) {
                putchar((*p >> k) & 0x01 ? dot : blank);
            }
            /*putchar(' '); */
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: VFONT.DAT is missing from the linked archive. I went on a journey, and found this, which *is* the Slackware archive centered on the font I was thinking about: http://www.ibiblio.org/pub/historic-linux/distributions/slackware-2.1/usr/lib/kbd/consolefonts/. The fonts are all broken out here.

Comment: @DavidKrider: Are you downloading CVFONTA.ZIP? Nothe the `A` at end of CVFONTA. I just downloaded it and it is present. Alternative link: http://kimludvigsen.dk/os2/gfd/wps/font/index.php where it is named cvfonta.zip – The fonts in your link also match up and is OK here, and a `diff` show them identical of the ones found in the mentioned ZIP-archive.

Comment: I did indeed miss that "A". Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I'm using the font now, and it's just as awesome as I remember.

Comment: Thank you.  With your recommendations I managed to convert t.fnt to t.ttf and now I am able to use it in konsole.